# how to bind association in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables, `AppTemplate` and `AppTemplateMeta`

`AppTemplate` table has column `id`, `MetaID`, `name` etc.

I have associated these two model like this

```
class AppTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'AppTemplate'
  belongs_to :app_template_meta, :class_name => "AppTemplateMeta", :foreign_key => 'MetaID'
end
```

If we fetch data using `AppTemplate.all`, I want associated meta details also. But currently it's not returning associated meta details. It just returns `AppTemplate` details.
any guys can help me for this

Comment: Did you add : has_one :appTemplate or has_many :appTemplates in the model of AppTemplateMeta? and it's probably : belongs_to :appTemplateMeta.

Comment: I'm confused by what you want for this... Of course AppTemplate.all only gives you AppTemplate details. You can always get the AppTemplateMeta if you need to on an individual template...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want something like the following:

```
# models
class AppTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  # table names usually looks like this: app_template.
  # the same for columns names. so you should have 'meta_id' as foreign key
  set_table_name 'AppTemplate'
  belongs_to :app_template_meta, :class_name => "AppTemplateMeta",
     :foreign_key => 'MetaID'
end

class AppTemplateMeta < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :app_template # or has_many
end

# controller
# get all app templates and load the associated app_template_meta for each one
@app_templates = AppTemplate.all(:include => :app_template_meta)
# get associated app_template_meta for the first app_template
@app_templates.first.app_template_meta
```

Comment: If this is the answer that solved your problem, you should accept it :]